# How to install SciPy for QGIS Standalone

Tags: qgis, python, installation

A number of QGIS plugins require the Python package SciPy to be installed. This package is available using the [OSGeo4W package based installer](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/osgeo4w-setup.exe) or [precompiled](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for Windows, but is not provided as part of the [Windows standalone installer](http://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-1.8.0-2-Setup.exe).

The [SciPy windows installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/latest/download?source=files) does not recognize the Python instance installed with the QGIS standalone install, and so will not install to it.

Can anyone provide a simple solution to installing the SciPy package into the QGIS standalone python instance that is suitable for an inexperienced python user? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you install using OSGeo4W or the stand-alone installer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the OSGeo4W-Version:
Nathan posted a really nice guide how to install additionall python libraries into an OSGeo4W Install on Windows.

See his [blog-post](http://nathanw.net/2012/12/19/installing-python-setuptools-into-osgeo4w-python/) for more information